# Diagonal clickable blocks in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to have the white blocks respond to click and hover events but as we all know the DOM is all rectangular blocks. So I'm really not sure how to approach this. The diagonal lines make it hard because I can't just put negative margins on the img elements and overlap them because then the clickable areas will overlap.

I'm open to solving with JS/Jquery IF necessary.

EDIT: I can't rely solely on CSS3 unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**Solution**
This is just an extract of that I actually did so it's a bit messy code-wise but here you go.
As noted below, I decided to go the CSS3 route since it degrades gracefully anyways.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Vgdu/1/

Comment: Can you show your html and css?

Comment: @EasyCo can't you use new css attributes like transform ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: http://mirificampress.com/permalink/diagonal_nav_rollover

Comment: @JamesMontagne I havent' started yet, just brainstorming how I'll approach the problem.

Comment: @Oddant I can't relie on CSS3 because of... ahem... IE

Comment: @Jawad I saw that a while back but it has the same problem. If you hover near the bottom where the top of the next image is it'll trigger the next image instead.

Comment: Yeah. That is the problem. That's why they call it the "Box Model". Sorry out of ideas.

Comment: @EasyCo if you can't use the Diagonal Nav, neither the CSS3, I can't see other solutions but using a script, with some conditional positions and maths maybe you'll do the job (hardly). CSS3 is for me the best method since it tends to be standardized and also reliable as a design utility.

Comment: I'm thinking I might just go the skew method so it'll degrade gracefully. No CSS3 support, no skew, no biggie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the skewX attribute of the css3 transform property:

[skewX examples](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skewx)

and then just apply a mousemove event on the transformed div

Answer (score 4):

I have read you can't use CSS3 because you need to support IE.

You can skew in IE6 and up using [matrix filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx). Not sure how the interactivity will be handled though, but worth a try.

You can translate skew to an IE filter matrix easily with this tool:

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

(doesnt' work in Chrome, use Firefox).

If the interactivity is handled fine, then filters + CSS3 skew can achieve what you need (mostly) cross-browser.

Comment: I ended up just using the CSS3 skew transform cause it still falls back nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<area>` tag to specify coordinates of any shape, no CSS3 necessary - see here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_area_tag.htm

Comment: That is only going to work if the boxes are a single image (or at least rectangular, including a slice of the one next to them), which I doubt.

Comment: It's an old site, but I used this technique [here](http://therincon.com/masterplan.html) for the map - note the irregular shaped piece at the bottom. It seems like the same principle would work here.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'll pass up on the <area> tag suggestion. I've used it in the past with limited success. All my previous experiences suggest that it's a pretty dated technique and it doesn't place nicely with jQuery... or jQuery doesn't play nicely with it.

Comment: Definitely dated, wouldn't have suggested it if not for the no-CSS3 req.

Answer (score 0):

As Oddant said, `transform: skew()` is probably your best bet if you can rely on CSS3.

If, on the other hand, you can't assume CSS3 support or you need the contents of the box *not* to be skewed, then you can only approximate the click areas as in the [example posted by Jawad](http://mirificampress.com/permalink/diagonal_nav_rollover).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know the coordinates of all your shapes, so you could just have your parent element clapture the click, or mousemove, or whatever event and use a little bit of math to figure out which element the mouse is currently in. I can't say I know the equation for figuring if a point lies in a shape like that off the top of my head, but I'm sure there is one.